# Adding a temporary column to a db_select query

Tags: 7, database

I'd like to add a temporary column with a fixed value to a database query. Eg a column called 'type' with a value of 'thing' for every result. I have tried using the `addExpression` and `addField` functions to do this but I'm not getting the right result.

Is this possible using `db_select`? I've tried the following:

```
$query = db_select('people', 'p')
   ->fields('p', array('id', 'date'));
$query->addField(':val AS type', array(':val'=>'thing'));
```

However this is executing the following query:

```
SELECT p.id AS id, p.date AS date
FROM 
people p
```

I suppose I'm trying to get drupal to do:

```
SELECT p.id AS id, p.date AS date, 'thing' as type
FROM 
people p
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use an expression, e.g.

```
$query = db_select('people', 'p')
  ->fields('p', array('id', 'date'));

$query->addExpression(':val', 'type', array(':val' => 'thing'));
```

Gives:

```
SELECT p.id AS id, p.date AS date, :val AS type
FROM 
{people} p
```

The replacement for `:val` will be injected when you execute the query.